# Migrate an existant project from Django 1.6 to 1.7

Tags: django, migration, django-1.7

I have a project running Django 1.6 with Python 2.7 and, for several reasons, I would like to upgrade to Django 1.7.

Consider that South has never been used in this project and that we have a custom user model (this is important to keep in mind because custom user models seem to clash with `convert_to_south` according to [this ticket](http://south.aeracode.org/ticket/1179)).

What would be the different steps to take in order to upgrade to Django 1.7 smoothly? My secret dream would be to avoid using South and directly take advantage of the native schema migration support of Django 1.7.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

from the db point of view:

- pip install django==1.7
- run `./manage.py makemigrations`
- run `./manage.py migrate`

that's all

for other compatibilities check release notes: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.7/

The main problems that you can find is related to the new [application loading](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.7/#app-loading-refactor) mechanism (ie you cannot use `get_user_model()` anywhere). There is no one way to solve it, depends by the code structure.

some 'everywhere valid' point are:

- if use custom user model. use always `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL` in ForeignKeys
- do not access to any Model in your `__init__`

some reference:

- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/upgrade-version/
- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-developers/lmT1JxsWHPo
- http://www.biggleszx.com/2014/09/notes-on-upgrading-to-django-1-6-and-1-7/

Comment: I prefer: "pip install django<=1.7.99" (1.7.1 is the latest version)

Comment: Check your settings you duplicstes in your INSTALLED_APPS

Comment: If you're jumping past 1.7, you'll need to do manage.py migrate --fake-initial, because that's the default in 1.7 but not in future versions